Generate Oracle database DDL without SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE
I need to generate the DDL for an Oracle database, including other owners' schemas, to recreate the database structure on another server. I understand this is usually done through Export Data or the DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL function. However, I don't have the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role, which is required for those. Can I manually generate the DDL using data dictionary views such as ALL_TAB_COLUMNS?

The ALL_ views will provide you with a full structure for generating DDL, but only for objects you have some kind of object privilege on. You won't be able to see information about objects you have no privs to.
The SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE is a very old role-based mechanism that has long been supplanted by the system priv SELECT ANY DICTIONARY. You could ask your DBA for that. If they refuse, then it sounds like the project you're trying to undertake is inappropriate. If you have a legitimate need to extract structure across all users, there shouldn't be a push-back on granting the privs to see all owners.

Are you sure that SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE has been supplanted by SELECT ANY DICTIONARY? As far as I can tell, they are both valid approaches to solving this problem. (Are you perhaps confusing the select role with DELETE_CATALOG_ROLE, which was deprecated in 12c?) In fact, I've generally found audits to prefer SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to the ANY privileges. Also, if the DBAs really don't want to grant either role or privilege, they could perhaps build a custom view or function that grants access to many users' objects but excludes system or sensitive users.
